# GetElementById Returns Undefined Value

Tags: javascript, c#, html, visual-studio, checkboxlist

I have a `CheckboxList` with 3 options.

In my javascript, I want to check which options are ticked.

But the validation did not go through as the `var` value retrieved is `undefined`.

*javascript:* **EDIT**

```
var schedule = document.getElementById("<%=ddlExecutionSchedule.ClientID%>").value; 
// ^ return as undefined

var schedule2 = document.getElementById("ddlExecutionSchedule").value;
// ^ return as undefined

var scheduleOptions = schedule.getElementsByTagName('input'); 
// ^ error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of undefined
```

*html:*

```
<div class="form-group" id="divExecutionSchedule">
<label class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblExecutionSchedule">Execution Schedule</label>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="input-group">
        <asp:CheckboxList ID="ddlExecutionSchedule" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="chkLabel" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" CellPadding="5" CellSpacing="5" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table" onchange="ToggleExecutionSchedule(this)" >
            <asp:ListItem Text="Daily" Value="Daily"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Weekly" Value="Weekly"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Monthly" Value="Monthly"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:CheckboxList>
    </div>
</div>
```

*c#:*

```
//if (ddlExecutionSchedule.Text == "Weekly") // <= Commented off to allow catering for multiple checkboxes to be ticked at the same time
    //{
    string selectedDay = item["Days"] != null ? item["Days"].ToString() : string.Empty;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedDay))
    {
        List<string> day = selectedDay.Replace(";#",";").Split(';').ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < chkSelectDay.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (day.Contains(chkSelectDay.Items[i].Value))
            {
                //Check only if they match! 
                chkSelectDay.Items[i].Selected = true;
            }
        }
    }
//}
```

I have went through the similar articles, and have tried several methods, including adding in `GetElementsByTagName`, but hit `Uncaught TypeError`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you see `document.getElementById("<%=ddlExecutionSchedule.ClientID%>").length` in console

Comment: @Mamun let me check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is returning `undefined` as the container of the checkbox list does not have any value so,

You need to loop through the CheckBox List to get the values of checked ones like:

Edit: As you have specified `ClientIDMode="Static"` so it wont be changing on runtime so, you can directly specify ID of the container

```
        //var chkBox = document.getElementById('<%= ddlExecutionSchedule.ClientID %>');
        var chkBox = document.getElementById('ddlExecutionSchedule');
        var options = chkBox.getElementsByTagName('input');
        var listOfSpans = chkBox.getElementsByTagName('span'); //change 'span' as per the page structure
        for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++)
        {
            if(options[i].checked)
            {
                alert(listOfSpans[i].attributes["JSvalue"].value); //change attribute as per the page structure
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can I also implement an additional check in the `if` statement? `if ((options[i].checked) && ((options[i].value)=="Weekly"))`

Comment: Yes, absolutely you can

Comment: Hi, the statement `var options = chkBox.getElementsByTagName('input');` is giving me error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of undefined`.

Comment: That is dependent on the page structure, show me the rendered code on browser or create an example on JS fiddle

Comment: I will take a look!

Comment: I tried your code, and it works. I just don't understand why your code passed without error but I encountered it in my code. The output are the same. Thanks, I'll continue to see what can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try removing double quotes i.e. `""` around `"<%=ddlExecutionSchedule.ClientID%>"` in js and just keep `(<%=ddlExecutionSchedule.ClientID%>)`.

this might help u

Answer (score 0):

Please remove `ClientIDMode="Static"` from below code.

```
<asp:CheckboxList ID="ddlExecutionSchedule" CssClass="chkLabel" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" CellPadding="5" CellSpacing="5" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table" onchange="ToggleExecutionSchedule(this)" >
    <asp:ListItem Text="Daily" Value="Daily"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Weekly" Value="Weekly"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Monthly" Value="Monthly"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckboxList>
```

or if you want to continue with `ClientIDMode="Static"` then write JS syntax as follow.

```
var schedule = document.getElementById("ddlExecutionSchedule").value;
```

this might help you.

Comment: Hi, I changed my JS syntax, but it is still returned as `undefined`

Comment: Hi, please remove ClientIDMode="Static" from checklist box.